# How to power Raspberry Pi Zero and other stuff not separately

Tags: pi-zero, printing

Here is the thing, I want to give the 2A and 5V power to my Raspberry Pi Zero and also I have a thermal printer that runs under 2A and 5V. How could I power those two elements without using two separately plugs?

I've tried with a USB plug with two outputs, but is unstable and the printer doesn't work properly. 
Thanks,

Comment: Why do people invent their own names for the Raspberry Pi and expect sensible answers? This question is incomprehensible.

Comment: You obviously wont be able to with the existing power supply. So what ever you hope to gain by this will be offset by the cost of a new powersupply.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use USB plug with two outputs, you'll need at least 4A power supply.

Comment: Thanks @giorgi but I've tried and the plug is not too stable  :(